# nuke-build nuke .tmp\shell-completion.yml blocked by another process

Tags: .net, dotnetnuke

I have **4.7 .NET Framework** project and try to build it using **Nuke 0.24.11**. When i start a script

`./build.ps1 --target npm --configuration Release --customerName 'Demo' --environmentName 'Prod'`

(doesn't depend on targets content) i get that error  ***The process cannot access the file 'C:....tmp\shell-completion.yml' because it is being used by another process***.

It reproducible for me only when i use the following attributes:

```
[TeamCity(
 TeamCityAgentPlatform.Windows,
 CleanCheckoutDirectory = false,
 VcsTriggeredTargets = new[] { nameof(Test), nameof(DeployBackend), nameof(DeployFrontend) },
 NightlyTriggeredTargets = new[] { nameof(Test), nameof(DeployBackend), nameof(DeployFrontend) })]
[AzurePipelines(
 AzurePipelinesImage.UbuntuLatest,
 AzurePipelinesImage.WindowsLatest,
 AzurePipelinesImage.MacOsLatest,
 InvokedTargets = new[] { nameof(Test), nameof(DeployBackend), nameof(DeployFrontend) })]
internal class Build : NukeBuild {
  ...
}
```

Nuke Logs:

> The process cannot access the file '....tmp\shell-completion.yml'
> because it is being used by another process.    at
> System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)
> at System.IO.FileStream.CreateFileOpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare
> share, FileOptions options)    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String
> path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32
> bufferSize, FileOptions options)    at
> System.IO.StreamWriter.ValidateArgsAndOpenPath(String path, Boolean
> append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize)    at
> System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path)    at
> System.IO.File.WriteAllText(String path, String contents)    at
> Nuke.Common.Execution.HandleShellCompletionAttribute.OnBeforeLogo(NukeBuild
> build, IReadOnlyCollection`1 executableTargets)    at Nuke.Common.Execution.BuildManager.<>c__DisplayClass5_0`1.b__3(IOnBeforeLogo
> x)    at
> Nuke.Common.Utilities.Collections.EnumerableExtensions.ForEach[T](IEnumerable`1 enumerable, Action`1 action)    at
> Nuke.Common.Execution.BuildManager.<>c__DisplayClass5_0`1.<Execute>g__ExecuteExtension|1[TExtension](Action`1 action)    at
> Nuke.Common.Execution.BuildManager.Execute[T](Expression`1[]
> defaultTargetExpressions)
>
> AzurePipelines configuration files have changed.
> #1/1: Process 'dotnet.exe' exited with code -1.
>
> > "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" ...\build\bin\Debug_build.dll --generate-configuration TeamCity
> > --host TeamCity    @ E:...
>
> at
> Nuke.Common.Tooling.ProcessExtensions.AssertZeroExitCode(IProcess
> process)    at
> Nuke.Common.CI.HandleConfigurationGenerationAttribute.InvokeGeneration(IConfigurationGenerator
> generator)    at
> System.Linq.Parallel.ForAllOperator`1.ForAllEnumerator`1.MoveNext(TInput&
> currentElement, Int32& currentKey)    at
> System.Linq.Parallel.ForAllSpoolingTask`2.SpoolingWork()    at
> System.Linq.Parallel.SpoolingTaskBase.Work()    at
> System.Linq.Parallel.QueryTask.BaseWork(Object unused)    at
> System.Linq.Parallel.QueryTask.<>c.<.cctor>b__10_0(Object o)    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__274_0(Object obj)    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread
> threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback
> callback, Object state)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread
> threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback
> callback, Object state)    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task&
> currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
>
> Repeating warnings and errors: AzurePipelines configuration files have
> changed.
> #1/1: Process 'dotnet.exe' exited with code -1.
>
> > "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" ...\build\bin\Debug_build.dll --generate-configuration TeamCity
> > --host TeamCity    @ E:...